# Renaming Serialized Auto-Properties in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, properties, rename

I have a auto-property that is serialized on the Inspector and i need to rename it without loosing the serialized value, normally i would use the [FormerlySerializedAs(previousName)] attribute for this, the problem is that it's not working with auto-properties, does anybody have any insight on this?

My code:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    [field: SerializeField]
    [field: FormerlySerializedAs("previousName")]
    public Transform FieldIWantToRemainSerialized { get; private set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Little late, but maybe someone will find that usefull, you need to use this:

```
[field: FormerlySerializedAs("<previousName>k__BackingField")]
```

Comment: I can't vote due to low points, but thank you.